# Sort list of dataframes by vector

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames, called `data.list` and a vector of the same length called `c`. The vector `c` contains only numbers, and I want to sort `data.list` by c and then chop of all but the top 10 elements of the sorted version of `data.list`.

I tried the following:

```
data.list <- order(c, data.list)
data.list <- data.list[1:10]
```

But the first command just turned data.list into a standard list of numbers. Even the labels for each element of data.list had disappeared. What do I do?

Comment: It'll be much better if you provide a list with at least 2 data.frames (reproducible example) and also show us the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my reading of OP (which lacks details):

```
l = list(data.frame(a = 1), data.frame(b = 2), data.frame(c = 3), data.frame(d = 4))
v = c(14,12,11,20)

l[order(v)]
#[[1]]
#  c
#1 3
#
#[[2]]
#  b
#1 2
#
#[[3]]
#  a
#1 1
#
#[[4]]
#  d
#1 4
```

Comment: eddi, `match(v, sort(v))` is `order(v)`. I think what the OP wants is `l[order(v)][1:10]`